# awk working on command line but not in script !? (quote issue with var ?)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm making a shell script to purge entries that are older than 2 months on a file which looks like that:

my test file:

```
1.2.3.8 2014-08-15
1.2.3.9 2014-09-08
1.2.3.10 2014-09-12
2.2.3.11 2014-08-08
2.2.3.1 2014-08-10
2.2.3.2 2014-07-31
2.2.3.3 2014-07-14
```

If today's date is October 11th, the script must only print IP starting with 1.x.x.x.

In command line, this works great:

```
$ awk '$2 > "2014-08-11"' MyTestFile
1.2.3.8 2014-08-15
1.2.3.9 2014-09-08
1.2.3.10 2014-09-12
```

But, when I try to put that in a shell script, it fails :(
The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Purge_Date=`date +%Y-%m-%d --date='2 month ago'`
echo "Purge all before : $Purge_Date"
awk '$2 > "$Purge_Date"' MyTestFile
```

The execution:

```
$ ./dnsbl_purge.sh
Purge all before : 2014-08-11
1.2.3.8 2014-08-15
1.2.3.9 2014-09-08
1.2.3.10 2014-09-12
2.2.3.11 2014-08-08
2.2.3.1 2014-08-10
2.2.3.2 2014-07-31
2.2.3.3 2014-07-14
```

I'm almost sure the problem comes from the var $Purge_Date not being interpreted (because of the " **'** " ), but I can't solve it.

Comment: maybe can try `awk '$2 > "'$Purge_Date'"' MyTestFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its because the `$Purge_Date` is a variable in the shell script which is unkown to the `awk`
```

pass the $Purge_Date`to awk script as argument using the`-v` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
Purge_Date=`date +%Y-%m-%d --date='2 month ago'`
echo "Purge all before : $Purge_Date"
awk -v purge=$Purge_Date '$2 > purge' MyTestFile
```

here `-v purge=$Purge_Date` sets the argument `purge` as your `$Purge_Date` which can be used in the awk